# How does the .htaccess mod_rewrite for my Site: http://bit.ly/2Ocf3B looks like, to have SEO friendly urls?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to optimize my site to make it SEO and user-friendly, I have several problems to set the right mod_rewrite for the urls and need help for this, I'm new to it, so it's way beyong my knowledge for the moment. http://bit.ly/2Ocf3B , the site should look like this: www.domain.me/category/subcategory . thanks

Comment: Please describe the structure of your site, how many categories and sub-categories it has, whether it has any resource directories etc. pp. I don't think anybody will want to pick that out from your site stucture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file that accepts two HTTP GET parameters, `category` and `subcategory`. Let's say `http://www.example.org/products.php?category=bicycles&subcategory=racing` yields an index of racing bikes.

To transform that URL into something prettier, say `http://www.example.org/bikes/racing`, enter this into your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)$      products.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2
```

As you can see, mod_rewrite revolves around regular expressions. If you don't know your way around them, I recommend you look into [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to get started. When you've learned the basics, it can be very educational to play around in a regex tester (I like [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/), but there are hundreds of alternatives).

Comment: Thanks FRKT, I'll try to gain more knowledge about the .htaccess, i just tought, someone could help me write a piece of code snipet that can make my urls look prttier. the problem with this is just that, my site has several urls, so i can't apply the conventional mod_rewrite here, i guess i need some additional code for my index file, i just need to figuer out how to do this.

Comment: @user257357: I think you'll just have to learn it. You'll thank me later. ;-)